# Handlebars helper for date parsing not getting the value

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I started playing around with EmberJS and Handlebars recently, so please accept my apologies for the silly question. I am trying to format a date shown in my template. The date is in a ISOString format and what I am trying to do is:

My template code:

```
{{parseDate toDate}} //toDate holds something like 2013-12-02T22:00:00.000Z
```

And my handler code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('parseDate', function(value) {
   console.log(value); //print string "toDate" not the value of "toDate" - the ISOString
   return dateString(value)
});
```

I am sure that this is something really simple, but could not figure it out. I have looked around but did not find a solution.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your `dateString` function does, but this helper works just fine: http://jsbin.com/odosoy/143/edit

I've changed very little, just added `Ember` namespace in front bevor `Handlebars` and converted it to a bound helper to make it rerender when your `toDate` property changes:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('parseDate', function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  // do any formatting to your value
  // I've commented this out since It's not clear from your
  // code example what the dateString function does
  // return dateString(value);
  return value;
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. It helped a lot. What I was missing was setting the helper as a BoundHelper(silly me) Thanks again for the quick help!

Comment: Nice and easy fix.. Worked for me too! Thanks